# conda install python=3.6 Unsatisfied Error

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am trying to install OpenCV through anaconda prompt for windows. However, when I run the command `conda install python=3.6` since I am currently on `3.7` I get this error message

> Solving environment: failed

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

- anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0 -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2']
- anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> mkl-service==1.1.2=py37hb782905_5
- importlib_metadata
- mkl-service
- pip -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
- zipp
```

Is there a reason why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a seperate conda environment with python 3.6 and do opencv installation.

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
source activate myenv
pip install opencv-python
```

you can import opencv using

```
import cv2
```